# How to use custom logo markup with Helix framework templates?

Tags: joomla-2.5, templates, overrides, template-override, helix3

Currently, my logo is displayed as so in my template:

```
<div id="sp-logo" class="span4">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <a href="/">
      <div style="width:300px; height:75px;" class="logo"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the logo is rather set as a background image for the div `#logo`. I need to change logo component code as such the logo would be displayed as an image (e.g.):

```
<div id="sp-logo" class="span4">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="http://imageurl/image.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I couldn't find such file in the template files, nor at Module manager.
So where does Joomla hide such component files.

*Note: Joomla version 2.51, template using Helix II*

Comment: Joomla 2.5.1 and your site isn't hacked yet?

Comment: The organization I am developing for does not want to upgrade PHP and MYSQL to support Joomla 3, regardless of how much I insisted on it.

Comment: Maybe you didn't make them clear what the consequences will be if they keep using outdated software. Also older versions of PHP are also insecure and not maintained any more. Whatever the case, even if upgrading PHP is not an option at the moment, you can still update to Joomla 2.5.28 and apply the required patches.

Comment: I was pretty clear with my description of the issues, and provided them references as a proof. Sadly they believe I am exaggerating.
I will upgrade to 2.5.28 indeed, wasn't aware of the fixed issues at this version.

Comment: just follow the recommended practices for updating to 2.5.28 - aka first backup the site (files/database) and make sure the backup is workable = can be restored. Remember to also keep your extensions updated. I would suggest using Akeeba Backup: https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all update at least to Joomla 2.5.28 and apply the required patches.

More info here:

- https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5643-joomla-3-4-7.html
- https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions

As for what you want to do, simply disable the logo feature from the template settings, and instead create a Custom HTML module containing your logo image only - name it Logo for your convenience, remember to set module's title to Hide and place it on the Logo position of your template.

If you want to go further with it, you can read on the [Helix documentation](https://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix-v2/subcategories)

Comment: Nice workaround, was thinking of something more from the template to be user for the end user, still, solves the issue indeed.

Comment: @Ken, for only using an image element in this case, the above solution is sufficient. No need to mess with modifying the template etc.